# Custom Validation Attribute reading from a form field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am trying to create my own validation attribute `IsUnique` that checks existing values for given property. I understand `IsValid()` must be overridden so that custom validation attribute can work. So far I have seen examples with validate attributes that take a string parameters which is then compared with hard coded values inside `IsValid()` method.

I need `IsValid()` method to get access to a property and its value to further compare it with values in the database.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public class IsUnique : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string codeno { get; set; }
            : base("{0} is already in use")

    public IsUnique (string codeno)
    {
        this.codeno = codeno;
    }

    public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                             ValidationContext vContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
            Student studentsCodeNo = 
                    db.Students.FirstOrDefault(r => r.codeno== (string)value);
            if (studentsCodeNo != null)
            {

                string errorMessage =
                        FormatErrorMessage(vContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

As said, the problem is that this version takes parameter. I would like `codeno` to be read from a user form field, and such value would then be compared against anything in database. I don't know how to read values from the form fields.

Comment: In the 'value' parameter of IsValid method you get the user input, is that what you need?

Comment: You can't validate against a form field using a validation attribute, the validation happens at a domain/data level it has no visibility of your UI. If you need to validate against an arbitrary value you will need to add an appropriate property to your model to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code

```
public class IsUnique : ValidationAttribute{

 public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                         ValidationContext vContext)
{

    PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("Codeno");
    if (property == null)
         return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Property '{0}' is undefined","Codeno"));

     var fieldValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
     string codeno= (fieldValue == null ? "" : fieldValue.ToString());
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codeno))
    {
        MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
        Student studentsCodeNo = 
                db.Students.FirstOrDefault(r => r.codeno== codeno);
        if (studentsCodeNo != null)
        {

            string errorMessage =
                    FormatErrorMessage(vContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have already been given good directions and help in comments. I needed someone to direct me to get a proper value from form fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is sort of an out of the box way to do this already
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx

```
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
```

Comment: It's somehow not working. I tried this but the same value has passed through validation and caused exception next to `db.SaveChanges()` because database could not accept the value that is already in use.

Comment: Sounds like it's working fine and that you're just not handling the error well. Wrap your controller business logic in a try catch and on catch, you can display the error on the page like this: ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);

Comment: It's working now :) Thanks. Though, I'd prefer to have a validation error message next to form fields. I've managed to create a custom validation attribute but another problem has just appeared. When I update the entity, the validation attribute is also applied and consequently causes error. I debugged the code and it goes through custom validation attribute. I tried overloaded `UpdateModel()` where you specify properties to update but eventually it updates everything, even those skipped :/